# Seems to get an error when trying to start webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, npm-run

Seem to have this problem even if i reinstalled it, deleted `node-modules/package-lock.json/` downgraded to a earlier version

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Users\\Shaimz\\Desktop\\work\\Programs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Shaimz\\Desktop\\work\\Programs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle my-app@1.0.0~prebuild: my-app@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle my-app@1.0.0~build: my-app@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle my-app@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle my-app@1.0.0~build: PATH: C:\Users\Shaimz\Desktop\work\Programs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Shaimz\Desktop\work\node\my-app\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\010 Editor;C:\FPC\3.0.4\bin\i386-Win32;D:\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\Shaimz\Desktop\work\Programs\;D:\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Shaimz\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\Shaimz\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle my-app@1.0.0~build: CWD: C:\Users\Shaimz\Desktop\work\node\my-app
10 silly lifecycle my-app@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'webpack' ]
11 silly lifecycle my-app@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle my-app@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: my-app@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Shaimz\Desktop\work\Programs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Shaimz\Desktop\work\Programs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid my-app@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Shaimz\Desktop\work\node\my-app
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
17 verbose argv "C:\\Users\\Shaimz\\Desktop\\work\\Programs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Shaimz\\Desktop\\work\\Programs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v10.16.3
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error my-app@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the my-app@1.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

WEBPACK config right here :

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var App = require('./components/App');

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
document.getElementById('app')
);
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
filename:'index.html',
inject:'head'
});
module.exports = {
entry:  ['./app/index.js'],
module:{
    loaders:[
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader:'babel-loader'
        }
    ]
},
output:{
    path:__dirname + '/build',
    filename:'file.js'
},
plugins:[HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

I think that's the formated code , sorry , i'm new to stackoverflow.I wish you could help me with that problem , i was starting to think maybe i do something wrong but i dont think soo , i was watching carefully a guide on codecademy

Comment: Why you use react inside your webpack config ?

Comment: i recently wanted to start to work in react ( initially ) and i was following this guide - https://www.codecademy.com/articles/react-setup-i / to install react , this guide was telling me to install webpack too and babel

Comment: well i kinda did it in a simplier way , npx create-react-app folder / cd folder npm start , thank you for your time anyway